# Slicing of Snowflake error message through Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-glue

I have a snowflake procedure throwing below error message if the source and target count does not match, which is being caught in AWS Glue python exception block:

```
100132 (P0000): JavaScript execution error: Uncaught The table: test_table is NOT balanced. Following are the balancing statistics: 
TABLE_NAME: test_table
SOURCE_COUNT: 17022 
TARGET_COUNT: 6585
BALANCED: N
 in SF_TABLE_PROC at '          throw err;' position 3
stackstrace: 
SF_TABLE_PROC line: 38
```

But I want to remove snowflake's default error message "100132 (P0000): JavaScript execution error: Uncaught" and the later part "in SF_TABLE_PROC at '          throw err;' position 3
stackstrace:
SF_TABLE_PROC line: 38".

Ideally my error message should only contain the main message body:

```
The table: test_table is NOT balanced. Following are the balancing statistics: 
TABLE_NAME: test_table
SOURCE_COUNT: 17022 
TARGET_COUNT: 6585
BALANCED: N
```

Snowflake proc block which throws the error message:

```
try
{
    if (tgt_count != src_count)
    {
        throw '\n' + 'The table: test_table is NOT balanced. Following are the balancing statistics: ' + '\n' + '\nTABLE_NAME: test_table' + '\nSOURCE_COUNT: ' + src_count + '\nTARGET_COUNT: ' + tgt_count + '\nBALANCED: N' + '\n';
    }
}
catch(err)
{   
    throw err;
}
```

where tgt_count: count(1) from target table and

src_count: count(1) from source table.

Is there any way I can slice the error message in snowflake or in python?
When I tried to slice the error message in python it gave me an error:
`TypeError: 'ProgrammingError' object is not subscriptable`
Below is my python code:

```
except Exception as error:
    print("Error: ", error[53:90])
    raise(error)
```

Please help me in retrieving the exact error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
from snowflake.connector import ProgrammingError
```

then:

```
except ProgrammingError as error:
    strError = str(error)
    print("Error: ", strError[53:90])
    raise(error)
```

Comment: Thanks @Sergiu. This solution worked. But how can I capture any python related issue? ProgrammingError is not handling any TypeError or NameError exceptions. I want to handle those too, as mentioned in my above exception block.

Comment: To use the Exception object to capture any Python connector related issues, check our docs [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#object-exception). We do follow [PEP-249](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/).